# hover appears behind image

Tags: html, css, hover, mouseover

so, I have this code:

```
    <section class="hero-cover">

      <div class="hero-text text-white">
            <p><h6>Memória Lage</h6><p>
            <p><h3>Parque Lage's history memorial</h3><p>
            <a href="project-eav.html"><button class="hero-button button-white"><h3>View Project</h3></a></button></p>
      </div>    

      <div class="hero-image eav-image revealOnScroll">
        <img src="images/hero-eav-cartaz.png" alt="">
      </div>

</section>
```

and im trying to add a hover to the whole section, like this:

```
.hero-cover {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
```

}

```
 .hero-cover:hover, .hero-cover:hover img {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
   transition: all .3s ease;
   -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
   -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
   -o-transition: all .3s ease;
   z-index: 1000;
 }
```

but it appears behind the image and text. what am I doing wrong here?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, can you create a codepen for this? So I can see what you mean? It's hard to visualize something from plain text :)

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with this hover effect?

Comment: @GerritLuimstra there you go http://codepen.io/tatiframbach/pen/KrXBbm :) I want the hover to be also on top of the text and image

Comment: Have you ever worked with jQuery? Since this is harded than it should using just CSS.

Comment: Is this what you want? [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKZBGq)

Comment: @RicardoRuiz this is definitly the best answer and most easy approach.

Comment: @RicardoRuiz that's perfect! thank you so much

Comment: @GerritLuimstra thank you for helping as well :)

Comment: @TatianaFrambach no problem!